# sphinx RT индекс - не видит поле

Tags: sphinx, sphinxsearch

Никак не пойму почему не видит поле, уже все перепробовал. Прошу помощи.

```
mysql> select id,title,city from index_rt;
+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+
| id      | title                                                          | city                   |
+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+
| 1354929 | XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                | XXXXXXXXXXX            |
+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id,title,city from index_rt where match('@title XXXXX');
ERROR 1064 (42000): index index_rt: query error: no field 'title' found in schema

index index_rt
{
    type = rt
    path = /var/www/..........

    # Описание всех полей для индексирования
rt_field = numbers
rt_field = title
rt_field = models
rt_field = engines
    #Описание атрибутов
rt_attr_string = did
rt_attr_string = numbers
rt_attr_string = sost
rt_attr_string = title
rt_attr_string = nal
rt_attr_string = orig
rt_attr_string = models
rt_attr_string = engines
rt_attr_string = city
rt_attr_string = text
rt_attr_string = images
rt_attr_string = price


    # Размер чанка для RT
    rt_mem_limit = 1024M
}
```

Answer (score 1):

После изменения конфига для rt индекса его нужно пересоздать, для этого удаляем все файлы rt индекса и перезапускаем sphinx - все новый конфиг применен.